# Give styling to placeholder in TextInput in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-textinput, react-native-text

So I've a TextInput and the placeholder has a styling. 
For this, I place a `Text` with `position: 'absolute'` and `zIndex: 1` before the `TextInput`

```
    activeField(){
        this.setState({active: true})
    }

render(){

  return(

      { !this.state.active &&
       <Text style={STYLES.textInputPlaceholder}>
          {this.props.placeholder}
       </Text>
      }

      <TextInput
        style={STYLES.textInputField}
        onFocus={() => this.activeField()}
      />

  )
}
```

Now, the Text component which has the placeholder, when I press on it, I should be able press at the placeholder, which is the Text component here and be able to call the `onFocus` method of TextInput

I hope I'm able to clearly explain my problem.

Comment: Hi Shubham, try my solution below. That should assist you :)

Answer (score 0):

We would not be able to trigger the `onFocus` event-listener of the `TextInput` by clicking on the `Text`. However, we can make it appear like that is happening with some clever CSS.

1. Make sure that the background of the `TextInput` is transparent or
   at least matching that of the `Text`. That way `Text` is still visible when we give `position: absolute`.
   Then we
2. We need the `zIndex` of the `Text` to be lower than the `zIndex` of the
   `TextInput`. That way `TextInput` is actually in front of Text. So while it looks like you're clicking on the `placeholder`, you are actually just clicking on the `TextInput` and that will trigger the `onFocus` event.

Try this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput } from "react-native";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    active: false,
    text: ""
  };

  activeField = () => {
    console.log("focused");
    this.setState({
      active: true
    });
  };

  handleOnBlur = () => {
    if (this.state.text.length === 0) {
      this.setState({
        active: false
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {!this.state.active && (
          <Text style={STYLES.textInputPlaceholder}>
            {this.props.placeholder}
          </Text>
        )}
        <TextInput
          style={STYLES.textInputField}
          onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text })}
          onFocus={this.activeField}
          value={this.state.text}
          onBlur={this.handleOnBlur}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const STYLES = StyleSheet.create({
  app: {
    marginHorizontal: "auto"
  },
  textInputField: {
    zIndex: 1,
    width: 300,
    borderColor: "black",
    borderWidth: 1
  },
  textInputPlaceholder: {
    zIndex: -1,
    color: "blue",
    position: "absolute",
    backgroundColor: "transparent"
  }
});

export default App;

App.defaultProps = {
  placeholder: "Hello"
};
```

Here's the working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-on23p